# Web Graph visualization when apache nutch is configured with cassandra

Tags: cassandra, web-crawler, nutch

I have configured my apache nutch with cassandra. I have read quite a few articles for the analysis post crawling to study URL link analysis.

The command 'bin/nutch webgraph -segmentDir crawl/segments -webgraphdb crawl/webgraphdb' is used to create a webgraphdb in your crawl folder. But since i've configured nutch with cassandra I don't have any segments to specify. Please suggest an alternative or a work-round